# How to resize context menu displayed with TrackPopupMenu?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, contextmenu

I display a context menu from a C++ code using TrackPopupMenu API. Each menu item contains a bitmap 24x24 pixels in size. Added by calling:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = {0};
mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
mii.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP;
mii.hbmpItem = hBmpForItem;
SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, ID_1_MENUITEMID, FALSE, &mii);
```

This works just fine on Windows Vista/7, but on Windows XP some menu items with a longer text get cut off on the right. So, I was wondering, is there any way to increase the width of the menu itself before it's displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Create your menu items as [owner-drawn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items), then have your menu owner window process the [WM_MEASUREITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775925.aspx) message so you can specify appropriate widths as needed.

Comment: Thanks. The issue with owner-drawn is that, well, I have to draw everything, which is not that easy with the modern UI.